# EventHubClient in hosted Azure Function throws System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I'm having an issue with a hosted Azure Function using an **EventHubClient** (Mircosoft.Azure.EventHubs) in an injected wrapper class of of our making, called **EventHubEventPublisher** (Injected using **AddTransient**). The function has been up and running in Azure for the past month with no issues, but yesterday it started to throw the following exception every time a function executes that calls **EventHubClient.PublishEvent()**.

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpEventHubClient+<CreateConnectionAsync>d__32.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1+<OnCreateAsync>d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Amqp, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1+<GetOrCreateAsync>d__13.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Amqp, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1+<GetOrCreateAsync>d__13.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Amqp, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpEventDataSender+<CreateLinkAsync>d__12.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1+<OnCreateAsync>d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Amqp, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1+<GetOrCreateAsync>d__13.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Amqp, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1+<GetOrCreateAsync>d__13.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Amqp, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpEventDataSender+<OnSendAsync>d__10.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpEventDataSender+<OnSendAsync>d__10.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.EventDataSender+<SendAsync>d__7.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.EventHubClient+<SendAsync>d__22.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Scrubbed_Name.Events.EventHubEventPublisher+<PublishEvent>d__5.MoveNext (Scrubbed_Name, Version=0.1.66.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
```

I'm hoping to get some insight as to what's going on in this stack trace. Our hosted Event Hub's metrics doesn't suggest that we're hitting the quota on Active Users, but restarting the Functions app in its entirety seems to have solved the issue for now; events are being processed. I'd like to be able to handle this situation gracefully in the future, or avoid it outright.

### Other facts about the code

- **EventHubEventPublisher** implements IDisposable, and the Dispose function closes the client connection, but the Azure Function itself does not call Dispose on it once all the work that needs to be done is completed. It was my understanding that an Azure Function should deallocate its resources once the function has completed. Is perhaps the way it's being injected as a Transient a problem?